# How Can I Create A Dump File of a Running Process in Linux?

Tags: linux, dump

I have a process that is spinning out of control under Linux, and I would like to create a dump file that I can take to my dev machine, and examine there.

In Windows, it is possible to create a "minidump" of a running program in several different ways, including ADVPlus and Windows Task Manager, by going to the Processes tab and right-click selecting "Create Dump File."

Is there a way to accomplish this in Linux?

I would need call stacks, heap and stack memory (especially stack), exceptions and all the rest.

Comment: Wondering if any of the replies was helpful to you?

Comment: @Valentin:  From an educational perspective, yes, the replies were helpful and I upvoted them.  However they did not answer the question I actually asked, which was how to construct a dump file which I can then take to a dev machine and examine.  I was looking for something analogous to a Windows minidump file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well the way to create a dump file is:

```
   gcore - Generate a core file for a running process
```

SYNOPSIS
       gcore [-o filename] pid

Answer (score 8):

```
pmap <PID>
```

or

```
strace -f -o xxx -p <PID>
```

might be the tools you are looking for.

pmap shows you an overview about the memory usage of the provided process. strace tracks down every action a process takes. With -f you tell strace to also consider watching over child processes and -o xxx tells strace to write the output to a file. You can also start a new process by using strace, e.g. with

```
strace cat /etc/passwd
```

If you are interested in specific information only, such as what files were opened, you can start strace accordingly:

```
strace -f -o xxx -e trace=open -p <PID>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
cat /proc/<pid>/smaps > mem.txt
```

[This](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Memory_Imaging) link might also help you.

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile ProcDump from the [Sysinternals suite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite) has also been made available under the very liberal MIT license from the [respective GitHub page](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProcDump-for-Linux).

```
Usage: procdump [OPTIONS...] TARGET
   OPTIONS
      -C          CPU threshold at which to create a dump of the process from 0 to 100 * nCPU
      -c          CPU threshold below which to create a dump of the process from 0 to 100 * nCPU
      -M          Memory commit threshold in MB at which to create a dump
      -m          Trigger when memory commit drops below specified MB value.
      -n          Number of dumps to write before exiting
      -s          Consecutive seconds before dump is written (default is 10)
   TARGET must be exactly one of these:
      -p          pid of the process
```

So as you can deduce from the command line arguments, it's easy to take "snapshots" of a process you know misbehaves by taking up undue amounts of resources to be later analyzed with `gdb` or so.

This ProcDump for Linux is, however, not feature-complete in comparison with its Windows cousin.